# Tweepy not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

So I was just trying to run a tweepy script to collect tweets. 
I've setup the database but now I'm running into an error.

```
Starting...
Started user: user1
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py",       line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 414, in filter
self.body['follow'] = u','.join(follow).encode(encoding)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string or Unicode, int found
```

EDIT: The script is actually using: from urllib import urlencode_noplus but the _noplus is not in the urllib which is why I simply deleted it from the code. Although I suspect this for causing the error..

```
import tweepy
import threading
import logging
from tweepy.models import Status
from tweepy.utils import import_simplejson
from urllib import urlencode
import json
import re

json = import_simplejson()

class Stream:

def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, 
                   key, secret, name):

    self.auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    self.auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
    self.tweetsBuffer = TweetsBuffer()
    self.name = name
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('TwitterCollector')
    #check credentials
    if not tweepy.API(self.auth).verify_credentials():
        print "Invalid credentials for user: ",self.name,".\nExiting..."
        logging.error("Invalid credentials for user: "+self.name+".\nExiting...")
        exit(0)

def run(self, users_list = None):

    sl = StreamListener()
    sl.init(self.tweetsBuffer)
    try:
        streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=self.auth, 
                                 listener=sl, 
                                 timeout=3000000000, 
                                 include_entities=1, 
                                 include_rts=1)


        #load friends
        filter = []
        if users_list is None:
            filter = tweepy.API(self.auth).friends_ids()
        else:
            for subList in users_list:
                for user in subList['users']:
                    filter.append(user.id)


        #remove duplicates
        filter = list(set(filter))


        sThread = threading.Thread(target=streamer.filter, args=(filter,))
        sThread.start()
        return sThread

    except Exception, e:
        print e

def getTweetsBuffer(self):
    return self.tweetsBuffer

def getUserList(self, lists):
    if lists is None:
        return None

    api = tweepy.API(self.auth)

    users_list = []

    for list in lists:
        users = []
        members = tweepy.Cursor(
                                api.list_members, 
                                list['owner'], 
                                list['slug']
                                ).items()
        for member in members:
            users.append(member)

        users_list.append(
                {
                'owner' : list['owner'],
                'slug'  : list['slug'],
                'users' : users
                })

    return users_list

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

def init(self, tweetsBuffer):
    #set buffer
    self.tweetsBuffer = tweetsBuffer

def parse_status(self, status, retweet = False):

    tweet = {
                 'tweet_id':status.id, 
                 'tweet_text':status.text,
                 'created_at':status.created_at,
                 'geo_lat':status.coordinates['coordinates'][0] 
                           if not status.coordinates is None 
                           else 0,
                 'geo_long': status.coordinates['coordinates'][1] 
                             if not status.coordinates is None 
                             else 0,
                 'user_id':status.user.id,
                 'tweet_url':"http://twitter.com/"+status.user.id_str+"/status/"+status.id_str,
                 'retweet_count':status.retweet_count,
                 'original_tweet_id':status.retweeted_status.id 
                                    if not retweet and (status.retweet_count > 0)
                                    else 0,
                 'urls': status.entities['urls'],
                 'hashtags':status.entities['hashtags'],
                 'mentions': status.entities['user_mentions']
            }

    #parse user object
    user = {
                'user_id':status.user.id,
                'screen_name': status.user.screen_name,
                'name': status.user.name,
                'followers_count': status.user.followers_count,
                'friends_count': status.user.friends_count,
                'description': status.user.description 
                               if not status.user.description is None
                               else "N/A",
                'image_url': status.user.profile_image_url,
                'location': status.user.location
                            if not status.user.location is None
                               else "N/A",
                'created_at': status.user.created_at
            }

    return {'tweet':tweet, 'user':user}

def on_data(self, data):

    if 'in_reply_to_status_id' in data:
        status = Status.parse(self.api, json.loads(data))
        if self.on_status(status, data) is False:
            return False
    elif 'delete' in data:
        delete = json.loads(data)['delete']['status']
        if self.on_delete(delete['id'], delete['user_id']) is False:
             return False
    elif 'limit' in data:
        if self.on_limit(json.loads(data)['limit']['track']) is False:
            return False

def on_status(self, status, rawJsonData):
    try:
        #parse tweet
        tweet = self.parse_status(status)
        tweet['raw_json'] = rawJsonData
        self.tweetsBuffer.insert(tweet)

        #parse retweet
        if tweet['tweet']['retweet_count'] > 0:
            retweet = self.parse_status(status.retweeted_status, True)
            retweet['raw_json'] = None
            self.tweetsBuffer.insert(retweet)

    except Exception:
        # Catch any unicode errors while printing to console
        # and just ignore them to avoid breaking application.
        pass

class TweetsBuffer():
tweetsBuffer = []

def __init__(self):
    self.lock = threading.Lock()

def insert(self, tweet):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.tweetsBuffer.append(tweet)
    self.lock.release()

def pop(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    tweet = self.tweetsBuffer.pop() if len(self.tweetsBuffer) > 0 else None
    self.lock.release()
    return tweet
```

Comment: Could you also add the code you have been using?

Comment: I'm on it @Pavlo ! :)

Comment: I think you are passing your args to streamer.filter incorrectly. You are invoking the tweepy function on a thread directly and the arguments will be applied by position. Perhaps you intended to pass your `filter` argument to `streamer.filter` as keyword `follow`. If `follow` were not the first argument to `streamer.filter` this would not be the case. Perhaps create your own function as target to the thread and invoke streamer.filter in there passing filter as keyword argument `follow`.